# McNemar or chi-square - test for group differences paired and unpaired data

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion, group-differences, mcnemar-test

I understand that the difference between a chi-square test of homogeneity and the McNemar test is that the chi square is used for unpaired data and the McNemar is used for paire data.

Here's my situation. I am running some tests on some devices and I am recording pass and fails, so basically 0 and 1 for each device. 
Week 1: I have let's say 5,000 devices and I have pass/fail results for each of them.
Week 2: additionally to those 5,000, I have another 3,000 devices.

My goal is to test whether or not there is difference between those 2 groups. The first group here being the 5,000 devices from Week 1. What should my second group be? 3,000 devices or 8,000 devices (i.e. combination from week 1 and week 2)

Here's my question: How do I set up my groups?
1- Do I have my first group being the 5,000 devices? 
2- Can I have my second group being the 8,000 devices, does it have to be the new 3,000 devices?
3- if answer to question 2 is that my second group has to be the new 3,000 devices, then the test to apply is a chi squared, correct? (unpaired data)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the difference between the 5000 and the 3000, I will have to be very general.  However, I think you already answered this here "*My goal is to test whether or not there is difference between those 2 groups.*"

Group A (n = 5000) and Group B (n = 3000) should be separate. Group C (n = 8000) can also be added, but any differences between B and C (for example) could be the result of the differences between A and B. Keep in Mind you'd be testing if A is different than A+B, which just means *'is A different than B?'*. Hopefully that makes sense? Again, I don't know if you are separating based on technology, brand, manufacturer, etc.

SO, to answer your question: the chi-squared for independence is correct. Keep the two groups separate, otherwise you are testing a portion of the same devices against themselves.